422 Unprocessable Content when testing a Form with PHPUnit in Symfony with an unmapped field
I keep getting an 422 Unprocessable Content whenever I tried to add the clients field to the form payload in my PHPunit test. I know I have to add the fields manually when they are unreachable. This is what I did, but to no avail.
I have the following test :
    $client = $this->entityManager->getRepository(ClientGroupe::class)->findOneBy([]);

    $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/secret/groupeclient/new');
    
    // Fill in the form fields with valid data
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Enregistrer')->form($this->formData);

    $formData = $form->getPhpValues();
    $formData['client_groupe']['clients'][0]['id'] = (string)$client->getId();

    // Submit the form
    $this->client->request($form->getMethod(), $form->getUri(), $formData, $form->getPhpFiles());

    $this->assertResponseRedirects('/secret/groupeclient');
    $this->client->followRedirect();

    $this->assertSelectorTextContains('div.alert', 'Groupe client ajouté');

for the following form type :
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('nom')
        ->add('groupeType', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => [
                'Groupe' => ClientGroupe::TYPE_GROUPE,
                'Association' => ClientGroupe::TYPE_ASSOCIATION
            ]
        ])
        ->add('affichagePrixHt')
        ->add('active')
        ->add('clients', CollectionType::class, [
            'mapped' => false,
            'required' => false,
            'entry_type'  => ClientRechType::class,
            'prototype' => true,
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
        ])
        ->add('canReceivePointFidelites', CheckboxType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'label' => 'Peut recevoir des points de fidélité'
        ])
    ;
}

The ClientRechType looks like this :
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('id', AutocompleteTextType::class, [
            'label' => 'Client : ',
            'class' => Client::class,
            'required' => false,
            'autocomplete_required' => false,
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => 'Recherche client par prénom ou nom ou email',
                'class' => 'js-autocomplete',
                'data-entity' => 'Client',
                'data-autocomplete-target' => 'champinput',
                'autocompleteurl' => $this->router->generate('ajax_admin_client_search'),
                'defaultvalue' => ''
            ]
        ])
    ;
}

Finally here is the payload when I submit it manually in the browser :
client_groupe[active]: 1
client_groupe[nom]: test name
client_groupe[groupeType]: 1
client_groupe[canReceivePointFidelites]: 1
client_groupe[clients][0][id]: 170222
client_groupe[_token]: a_long_token_string

I just don't understand the correct way to add an unmapped field manually to the form.
Thank you !
